# How do I restart a systemd service from github action with a conditional if statement

Tags: github-actions

I am trying to provide a conditional if statement for the commands to run based on whether its the release branch or any other branch (dev)

```
      - name: Restart App Server release
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
        if: ${{ contains(github.ref_name, 'release') || github.ref == 'refs/heads/release' }}
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.SSH_HOST }}
          username: ${{ secrets.SSH_USER }}
          key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
          port: ${{ secrets.SSH_PORT }}
          # from ./bin/post-deploy.sh
          script: |
            cd $HOME/www/${{secrets.HOST_PATH_PROD}}/${{secrets.HOST_PROJECT}}
            deno upgrade
            sudo /etc/init.d/nginx reload
            sudo systemctl daemon-reload
            sudo systemctl restart ${{secrets.META_SERVICE_PROD}}
      - name: Restart App Server development
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
        if: ${{ !contains(github.ref_name, 'release') || github.ref != 'refs/heads/release' }}
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.SSH_HOST }}
          username: ${{ secrets.SSH_USER }}
          key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
          port: ${{ secrets.SSH_PORT }}
          # from ./bin/post-deploy.sh
          script: |
            cd $HOME/www/${{secrets.HOST_PATH_DEV}}/${{secrets.HOST_PROJECT}}
            deno upgrade
            sudo /etc/init.d/nginx reload
            sudo systemctl daemon-reload
            sudo systemctl restart ${{secrets.META_SERVICE_DEV}}
```

I've tried using `if:` but that doesnt'' seem to work except with `run:`

Answer (score 1):

I believe your issue it due to a Boolean condition. I think you want this line to be an `AND` operation:

```yaml
if: ${{ !contains(github.ref_name, 'release') && github.ref != 'refs/heads/release' }}
```

Since `github.ref_name` is a subset or simplified version of `github.ref`, the name of your release branches could be causing the confusion here.

For example, let say you have a release branch called `release/v1`. The `ref_name` would be `release/v1` making the left side of the condition evaluate to `false`. But the `ref` value would be `refs/heads/release/v1` making the right side evaluate to `true`. Since you had an `OR`, the `Restart App Server development` step would always run because at least one of the conditions was true.

You likely may not need the `github.ref != 'refs/heads/release'` depending on how you name your branches.

Comment: That was a bug but didn't resolve the issue. The step isn't completing with no messages indicating why

Comment: Which step isn't completing? Your issue might be with the GitHub Action `appleboy/ssh-action`. I was able to a basic scenario working here: https://github.com/tjc-actions-demo/simple-actions/actions/runs/4115143801

Comment: yeah `if/run` works fine. that's not my issue.

Comment: i need to move this to the script tag: `if [ ${{ contains(github.ref_name, 'release') || github.ref == 'refs/heads/release' }} ]; then`
 how can i do that condition?

Comment: I think I'm missing something. Why do you need to move it to the `script` section? To clarify, the `script` element is an input to the action you are using so there is no way in GH Actions to add an `if` to it unless you put the logic directly in your script.

Comment: right that's what i'm doing. the `if:` doesn't work with this module

Comment: Think of `with` as parameters to a function call to the action you specified in the `uses`. The `if` expression is used to control the execution flow of the workflow itself. When you try to use the `if` in the `with` section, it's going to treat it as parameter to the action. Based on what I'm seeing, you will need two distinct steps with the `if` to control execution or modify your script to understand what environment you are in.

Comment: Can you provide a working example @tj-cappeletti